# How to continue in Git after closing terminal?

Tags: git

beginner user here trying to learn git. I was writing a simple program, using checkout -b and commit -m with a note, to 'save' my progress along the way. I used status and branch to check and see that the branches were being made, but i closed the terminal. Now i use git status and it says i am on a branch but lists 'no commits yet' underneath. THe JS i have been writing along the way is still there.

Should i be using commit A every time i use commit M? I cant tell if I am having an issue because I am starting up wrong or saving my branches wrong.

Comment: did you add the files?

Comment: Closing the terminal (when no git command is currently running!) and reopening it has no effect on git, even if you reboot in between. There must be something else wrong (wrong branch, not committed, wrong directory/repository, ...).

Comment: The way you have written the post, I'm getting the impression that you committed to one branch then switched to another branch? It would be helpful if you listed the git commands in the exact order that you performed them so that we can find any potential issues.

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel A. White said, you have to add files before you commit.

Before you can create a commit you have to tell to git which files you want to include in the commit (Aka move it to the staging area). You can `git add .` (prepare the content staged for the next commit - it is safer to to use the command `git add -u` which adds only the files which are already tracked - thanks to knittl to pointing this out) and `commit -m "some commit message"`or `git commit -am "message"` (this command automatically stages the files and creates a commit with the given message)

Comment: NB. Avoid `add .`, because it is too easy to add files which should not be tracked (build artifacts, backup files, etc.). Less errorprone to list each file explicitly. If you already have tracked files and want to stage all "changed", use `git add -u`

Answer (score 1):

Your files are just in your *work-tree*.  You have not yet committed anything!  There's no harm done, you can add and commit your files now.  But you will definitely have to use `git add` first.

## Long

As a beginner using Git, you will be starting in one of two "modes", as it were, and they require somewhat different approaches.  **There is a unifying theme underneath this but it helps to start without it!**  Note: this is pretty long, but I recommend you read through it all.

#### Mode #1: you are starting on your own, without cloning some repository

In this mode, you need to create a directory and enter it—you may have done this already—and then run `git init`:

```
$ mkdir new-project
$ cd new-project
```

(you might have done these steps already)

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .../new-project/.git
```

You can now create files in the `new-project` directory that you are already in, or you might already have some files there.  If you run `git status` you will get:

```
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

(older versions of Git don't say "no commits yet" as they print a longer and stupider message that means the same thing, but is confusing.)

**In this mode, there is no need to run `git checkout -b`.**  It won't really hurt if you do, but there is a weird thing going on: you're on branch `master` but branch `master` *does not exist yet*.  If you use `git checkout -b` to change which branch you're on, you'll continue to have no branches.  You'll be "on" whichever branch you select, and it will still not exist!

Having created some files, you *must* now run `git add`.  The `git add` step copies the files to the *staging area*—a hidden file inside the `.git` directory, really—so that they will be in your next commit.  **You cannot use `git commit -a` here** as we will see in a moment.

If you run `git commit` without first running `git add`, the commit attempt will fail:

```
$ echo I am a readme file > README
$ ls
README
$ git commit -m "a bad commit message"
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
        README

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        README

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

**Note that `git status` still says `No commits yet`**.  The `git commit` command did not do anything!

There is no harm done here, as you can now `git add` your files and `git commit` them.  That's what you need to do in this particular case: just open a terminal window again, navigate to your project (`cd new-project` or whatever), and then use `git add` and `git commit`.

#### Mode #2: you are starting by cloning someone else's repository

In this mode, you start with:

```
git clone <url>
```

where the *`url`* part comes from someone else, perhaps GitHub for instance:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/git/git
Cloning into 'git'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 273170 (delta 1), reused 1 (delta 1), pack-reused 273168
Receiving objects: 100% (273170/273170), 122.67 MiB | 3.53 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (202836/202836), done.
$
```

At this point you're not in the project yet, and must still navigate into it:

```
$ cd git
```

Now you have an *existing* project—in this case, the source code for Git—with a lot of existing commits holding a lot of existing files.  The output from running `ls` here is long and I won't show it at all.

The key difference is that at this point, you have:

- a branch (probably master)
- some number of *remote-tracking names*, such as `origin/master`
- lots of *tracked* files in your work-tree

You can now modify files and use `git commit -a`, if you like (though I recommend against it).  You can use `git checkout -b` to create a new branch first, and this one actually *does* create a new branch.

#### Why these are so different?

Actually, they're not as different as they might look at first.  The real key is that the `git clone`-d repository *has some commits in it*.

To Git beginners, it might seem that Git is all about branches.  It's not, really—it's all about *commits*.  Branches—or really, branch *names* like `master`—are important because they help Git, and thus also help you, *find* commits.  It might also seem that Git is all about files, but it's not: it's about commits.  Commits *hold* files, but really, the commit is the basic unit of Git.

It's also worth noting here that `git clone` really means:

- Run `mkdir` and then enter the directory and run `git init`, to make a new, totally-empty repository.
- Add the URL under a name.  The standard name here is `origin`, though you can choose another one if you want.
- Use the name and its stored URL to run `git fetch`, to obtain commits from some other Git.  There needs to be a Git listening at that URL.  That Git has commits; that Git gives you their commits.  That Git has branch names that that Git is using to *find* those commits, so that Git gives you its branch names too.  That Git may have *tag* names that it can also use to find commits; if so, that Git gives you their *tag* names.
- **Rename** all of their branch names.  These become your *remote-tracking* names: their `master` becomes your `origin/master`; their `maint` becomes your `origin/maint`; and so on.  (If that Git gives you some tag names, your Git just takes them as-is.)
- Pick one of their branch (or tag) names, usually `master`.  Which one to pick is a little tricky.  You can tell your Git, at `git clone` time, which one to pick, including tag names.  If you don't pick one, *their* Git is supposed to *recommend* a particular branch name—never a tag name—and your Git will pick that one.  If all else fails, your Git picks `master`.

As its final step, your `git clone` takes the name picked by the last step above and creates—or tries to create—that branch name in *your* repository, matching the one it got from the other Git.  If we assume the name is `master`, you now have a `master` branch that matches your `origin/master`, and some commits.  This creating-your-master is done via `git checkout`: your Git checks out *their* `master` branch's commit—which is your `origin/master`—and then adds your own name `master` to identify the *same commit*.  We'll see more about this below.

There is one weird case: if you clone a totally-empty repository—one that has *no* commits—it won't have any branch or tag names either, and your Git will be unable to get a recommended branch or tag name from them and be unable to create a `master` branch.  This puts your Git back in the situation you had in mode #1!

In other words, **the real difference is whether you have some commits** to start with.  **Git is all about commits, and with no commits, Git is kind of helpless and useless.**  The very first commit is really important: not its *contents*, not that much, but its existence.  Until you have a first commit, you *cannot* have any branches or tags.

#### A branch name identifies a commit

One of the big secrets—ok, not actually secret at all—to understanding Git is to learn that a *branch name* like `master` just holds the *hash ID* of one single Git commit.  Every Git commit has a big ugly hash ID, such as [`745f6812895b31c02b29bdfe4ae8e5498f776c26`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/745f6812895b31c02b29bdfe4ae8e5498f776c26).  This hash ID is unique to *this particular commit*.  No other commit can have this ID.  But who wants to try to remember 745f6-something-something-whatever?  We have a *computer*, why don't we have the *computer* remember it, and give it a nice simple name, like, say, `master`?

That's precisely what a branch name *is and does:* it's a nice simple name that remembers some big ugly hash ID *for* us.  What makes branch names special, though, is that they don't just remember *some* hash ID.  Instead, they remember the *latest* hash ID.

As you make *new* commits, Git will *move* your branch name—the name of whichever branch you have checked-out—so that it remembers the hash ID of the *last* commit.  Each new commit you make will automatically remember the hash ID of the *previous* commit.  So, by starting at the end and working backwards, Git can find its way to each previous commit:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

If `H` stands in for the hash ID of the last commit, and `G` stands in for `H`'s remembered "previous commit" hash ID, we say that `H` *points to* `G`.  The name `master` points to `H`.  From `H`, Git can find `G`; from `G`, Git can find `F`.  This repeats until we get all the way back to that very first commit.  The *first* commit can't point to any earlier commit, so it just doesn't.

To make a *new* commit—let's call it `I`—we have Git write out all our files into a new commit, add our log message and our user name and all that stuff, and set `I`'s *previous* commit to be commit `H`, so that `I` points back to `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I
```

Then all Git has to do is to write the hash ID of `I` into the name `master`, so that `master` now points to `I`, and the commit is done and incorporated into our Git repository:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master
```

When you make new commits, the existing commits stay put.  The *new* commit points back to some previous, existing commit.  The *branch name* changes to point to the new commit.

When you start with a totally-empty repository, though, there *are no commits* for any names to point to.  Git requires every branch name to point to some existing commit, so no *names* are allowed to exist either.  **This is why Git is a little weird and useless on a new, totally-empty repository:** with no commits to point-to, no branches can exist!  You *must* make that first commit.  From then on, you can have as many branch names as you want—though if there's only *one* commit, *every* branch name will point to that one commit!

```
A   <-- branch1, branch2, branch3, ..., branchN, master
```

Here, *all* branches just have the one commit, which we're calling `A`, but which actually has some big ugly hash ID as its real name.

Note that you can *remove* branch names at any time, too.  If we have the above, and remove all the `branchnumber` names, we get back to a much more sensible:

```
A   <-- master
```

and now there's just one branch `master` holding the one commit that is in this repository.

Remote-tracking names work the same way, except that instead of *your* Git moving them, the *other* Git moves *its* branch names.  You then have your Git call up their Git, find out where their branch names have moved, and have your Git move your remote-tracking names to match:

```
A   <-- master, origin/master
```

If they add a new commit `B`, *their* `master` will point to this new `B`.  You run `git fetch` and you get:

```
A   <-- master
 \
  B   <-- origin/master
```

because your Git sees that *their* `master` now identifies (new) commit `B`, so your Git brings over commit `B` to your repository, then updates your remote-tracking name `origin/master`.

#### What to know so far

- Branch names find the *last* commit in a branch.  If you have another Git you're calling `origin`, your *remote-tracking names* `origin/*` remember *their* branch names, which remember the last commit in *their* branch.
- Each commit points backwards to its previous ("parent") commit.  The first commit is kind of special, because there *isn't* a previous commit.
- The set of branches that hold some commit can *change* when you add or remove branch names.
- Making a *new* commit updates the *current* branch name—the one you gave to `git checkout`.
- Until you have at least one commit, *no* branch names can actually exist, even though `git checkout -b` will change the name of the branch that you're "on".
- If you're on a branch that doesn't exist—in a new, totally empty repository, for instance—making a new commit will make that branch spring into existence.

So this is how you will bootstrap your initial, totally-empty repository: by making that first commit, you'll create whatever branch you chose to be on.  The usual normal way to do this is to let that first branch be called `master`.  (Some external tools, and/or some people, will get confused if you make your first branch something else: everyone *expects* `master`.  [If you call it `the-spanish-inquisition`....](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAn7baRbhx4))

#### A clearer picture of commits

We noted above that while Git is all about *commits*, each commit *holds* some set of files.  In fact, each commit represents a full snapshot of *every* file—well, of every file that goes in that commit, but that seems kind of redundant.  We didn't note—but it's important—that everything in *every* commit is frozen for all time.  Nothing about any existing commit can ever be changed!  The user name and email address that Git put in that commit, the log message you entered, the frozen copies of every file in the snapshot: all of these are quite impossible to change.<sup>1</sup>  The commit with that hash ID *always* contains those copies of files.  If you have that commit, you have that version of all the files: you have *that* snapshot.

Now, obviously, if Git made *new* copies of every file every time you make a new commit, the repository would rapidly become terribly fat.  So Git doesn't actually do that.  When Git freezes copies of your files, it uses a couple of tricks.  The first trick is that it *compresses* the file.<sup>2</sup>  So what's inside Git is sort of a dehydrated version of your file, that's also frozen for all time.  I like to call this a *freeze-dried copy* of the file.  The second and perhaps more important trick is that, having made this freeze-dried copy that can never be changed, Git can just keep *referring back to the existing copy* in every new commit that re-uses that file unchanged.

Hence, if you have six commits—six snapshots—of your files, but five of the six have the same contents for the `README` file, all five of those snapshots share one underlying freeze-dried `README`, and the sixth has its own currently-private freeze-dried copy.  If a later commit wants to use the same data for any file—even if it's not named `README`—Git can just re-use one of those freeze-dried copies.

This gives us a clearer picture of what a commit *is:*

- It has some metadata to say who made it and when: author and committer, name and email address, and two time-stamps for when-authored and when-committed.
- It has the hash ID of its predecessor or *parent* commit.
- It stores freeze-dried copies of *every* file that goes with that particular commit.  They might be shared with other commits, but there's a full copy of every file for this particular snapshot.  But they're in a freeze-dried format that nothing but Git can use.
- It has any arbitrary metadata you'd like to see later, say, in a year or two when you look back at this commit: the log message.

Putting all of this stuff together is what gets us the hash ID of the commit.

There are a couple of problems, though.  The first and most obvious is: freeze-dried copies of files that only *Git* can read—and never change—are not going to help us get any actual *work* done.

---

<sup>1</sup>The reason for this ties into the unique hash ID for each commit.  The hash ID of a commit is actually a cryptographic checksum of its contents.  This means that if you take a commit out, make some change to the contents, and try to put the result back, what you get is a *new and different* commit with a new, unique hash ID.  The original commit is still there, untouched!  All you did was *add* a new commit.  This becomes particularly important later (but not in this answer).

<sup>2</sup>Technically, what Git does is to use zlib deflate on the *object*, rather than on the file itself.  The object is a Git *blob* that holds the file's data.  This is not really all that crucial, although as a happy side effect, it also protects against using the one known ["shattered" PDF file SHA-1 collision](http://shattered.it/).

---

#### How new commits get made, or why you have to run `git add`

In order to get any work done, Git needs to give you the ability to *extract* any given commit.  The place where you extract the commit is your *work-tree* or *working tree*, or some variation on this name.  You run `git checkout`, and give it a hash ID or a branch name—something that finds some particular commit in your repository—and your Git fills in your work-tree *from* that commit.

In a new, totally-empty Git repository, you still have a work-tree.  You can do whatever you want in this work-tree.  Git just creates it as an initial, empty—well, mostly-empty—directory or folder (whichever term you prefer).  In your work-tree, Git hides a sub-directory / sub-folder named `.git`, and Git keeps all of *its* files in this `.git` directory.<sup>3</sup>

Note that other than filling it up with files (and sub-directories if needed to hold files), and copying files back out of it when you use `git add`, Git doesn't actually *do* anything with your work-tree.  The work-tree is for *you*, not for Git.  This is where things get a little weird.

In other version control systems, such as Mercurial (`hg`), you work in your work-tree and then you run `hg commit`.  The VCS scans your work-tree to see what you changed, and makes a new commit with the changes from the work-tree.  Git doesn't do that—it doesn't store *changes*, and it doesn't scan the work-tree.

If you had just the repository itself plus the work-tree, you'd have *two* copies of each of the files from the current commit: the frozen copy that Git used to fill the work-tree when you did a `git checkout`, and the normal-format copy in the work-tree.  That's how `hg checkout` works and it all makes perfect sense.  If you want to *change* the file, you just change it in the work-tree.  The work-tree is your proposed *next* commit.  But that's not what Git does.

Instead, Git adds a *third* copy of each file.  This third copy goes into what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or (rarely these days) the *cache*.  These three names all refer to the same thing.<sup>4</sup>  The index holds the freeze-dried copy of the file, just like the commit.  This freeze-dried copy is automatically ready to go into any *new* commit that you might make.

When you run `git add`, Git reads and compresses—i.e., freeze-dries—the *work-tree* copy of the file and stuffs that into the index / staging-area.  So `git add` makes the file ready to commit again.  If the file *wasn't* in the index *before*, now it is.  If it *was* in the index before, it's been replaced.  Either way, the file is now ready to be committed.

This means that when you run `git commit`, all Git has to do is package the pre-frozen files that are *already in the index* into a new commit.  That's (mostly) why, if you have a big project and run `git commit`, it happens almost instantly—but if you're using Mercurial and run `hg commit`, it takes *seconds* before it responds.  Mercurial has to scan the work-tree.  Git can *ignore* the work-tree.<sup>5</sup>

This index or staging area—whichever name you prefer—is, in effect, the proposed next commit.  It's in a form that makes `git commit` go fast.  But this puts a burden on *you*, the programmer: *you* have to run `git add` to copy files *into* the index / staging-area before you commit them.

Git *does* offer `git commit -a`.  What this does, in effect, is have `git commit` run `git add -u` first.  The `git add -u` option tells `git add` that it should *read through the index / staging-area*.  For each file that is *already in the index*, `git add -u` checks the work-tree copy to see if it needs to be `git add`ed to overwrite the existing index copy.  But files that are not *in* the index are what Git calls *untracked*.

This is very important so let's say it again: **In Git, an untracked file is a file that is not in the index.**  You can put a file into the index using `git add`, and you can take a file out of the index using `git rm`.

Whenever a file *not* in the index, it is *untracked*, and it will not be in the next commit.  However, it may still be in some existing commits.  If you `git checkout` this *old* commit, Git will *copy the file into the index*, and now it *is* in the index and is tracked.  If you then `git checkout` the new commit that *doesn't* have the file, Git will remove the file from the index **and from the work-tree**, and the file will no longer be tracked, but also will be gone from the work-tree!  If you have a configuration file, and don't want it to be in every commit, try not to put it in *any* commit.

Again, `git commit -a` means *scan the index, and for each file that is there—is tracked—check to see if a `git add` will update the index copy; if so, do it.*  This means that `git commit -a` makes Git work a lot like `hg commit`.  Mercurial requires that you `hg add` a *new* file, to put the file into what Mercurial calls its *manifest;* `hg commit`, and other `hg` commands, use the manifest to know which work-tree files are tracked and which ones are untracked.  Git uses the index, rather than the manifest, to know which work-tree files are tracked.

It's tempting to try to ignore the existence of the index, by using `git commit -a` all the time.  I recommend that you *do not* do this.  Git's index is ridiculously important later—it plays a huge role in `git merge` when there are conflicts—and you'll need to know about it.  Don't try to ignore it!  If you ignore it, it will come out and bite you when you least expect it.

---

<sup>3</sup>Try not to touch most of the files inside the `.git` directory, at least not at first: Git may not be able to recover from things you change here.  You can *look* at it all you like, though.  Note in particular that there's a file `.git/config` that contains your configuration data—the stuff that `git config` manipulates.  You can run `git config --edit` to edit it in whatever editor you like, which is pretty handy if you have used `git config` to do something long and had a typo in it.

<sup>4</sup>The actual implementation is mostly just a file named `.git/index`.  This file is binary and has a kind of complicated internal format.  What's in the index, for each file, isn't the file itself, but rather the hash ID of an internal Git *blob* object.  Initially, the blob object is the one from the commit.  Whenever you update the copy of the file in the index, Git actually writes out a new blob object—or reuses an existing one, if there is one—then makes the index entry refer to the new-or-reused blob.

<sup>5</sup>There is actually a lot more to it than this, but this makes for a good mental model, I think.  Git really gets its speed from a lot of other tricky optimizations, many of which *could* be put into Mercurial but haven't been, and from being compiled rather than interpreted Python, and a lot of other things.  But at a sort of fundamental level, Mercurial is *required* to look at the work-tree—the work-tree *is* the proposed next commit—and Git isn't because the *index* is the proposed next commit, and that means Git's job is always going to be easier.

---

#### Summary

- A Git repository has, at all times, *three* copies of each "active" file:

  - the frozen copy in the current commit;
  - the current staged copy: frozen format, but replaceable with `git add`;
  - the work-tree copy.
- Except, that is, in a new, totally-empty repository when there is no current commit: then there are only two copies.
- The index or staging area holds your proposed *next* commit.
- Use `git add` to copy files from the work-tree into the staging area.  Use `git rm` to remove files from both the work-tree *and* the staging area.
- Any file that *is* in the staging area right now is *tracked*.  Any file that *isn't* in the staging area right now is *untracked*.
- `git commit` will simply package up whatever is in the staging area *right now*.  Adding `-a` will make it run `git add -u` first, and `git add -u` will only look at *tracked* files.
- `git checkout` can check out any existing commit.  To do so, it will copy all the files from that commit into both the index/staging-area, and the work-tree.
- If you `git checkout` a *branch name*, that branch name is now the current branch, and `git commit` will make the branch name identify the *new* commit you just made.  The commit you had out earlier will be the parent of the new commit.
- The very first commit ever is special because it allows branch names to exist.  Before that point, you can change which branch name you're on, but no branch names exist.  The name you're on will be *created* by that very first commit.

(There's actually a way to get into that special mode even when you do have a bunch of branches, using `git checkout --orphan`, but let's avoid that topic here as this is already plenty long.)